# Unity3d - IntemDatabase.cs gives an error (FormatException: Input string was not in the correct format)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

G'day,

I am currently working on a Unity3d project and get this error while working on the ItemDatabase.cs file. The code looks fine to me but I get the error for some reason. Could I please get some help with fixing the error.

Thanks,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUETY.png

ItemDatabase.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;


[System.Serializable]
public struct Item
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
    public bool Stackable;
    public string Slug;

    public Item(int id, string name, bool stackable, string slug){
        ID = id;
        Name = name;
        Stackable = stackable;
        Slug = slug;
    }
}

public class ItemDatabase : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<Item> itemDatabase = new List<Item>();


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        GetDatabase("Assets/Resources/ItemData.txt");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void GetDatabase(string path)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
        AddItem:
        itemDatabase.Add(new Item(
            int.Parse(sr.ReadLine().Replace("id", "")),
            sr.ReadLine().Replace("name: ",""),
            bool.Parse(sr.ReadLine().Replace("stackable: ","")),
            sr.ReadLine().Replace("slug: ","")
        ));

        string c = sr.ReadLine();
        if(c == ",")
        {
            goto AddItem;
        }
        else if(c == ";")
        {
            sr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So it’s telling you somethings not an int. debug it?

Answer (score 0):

The error message here is quite explicit in what it's telling you - you're calling `int.Parse()` on a string that it can't recognise as an integer value here:

```
itemDatabase.Add(new Item(
    int.Parse(sr.ReadLine().Replace("id", "")),
    sr.ReadLine().Replace("name: ",""),
    bool.Parse(sr.ReadLine().Replace("stackable: ","")),
    sr.ReadLine().Replace("slug: ","")
));
```

You're going to need to double-check what input you are passing to `GetDatabase` and go from there.